# Solr - multivalued relation

Tags: solr, schema, dataimporthandler

I have a file with the following contents. the character '.' denotes space.

```
#itemcode            type              color

abc..................lime..............red........
abc..................lime..............blue.......
abc..................nectarine.........red........
abc..................nectarine.........blue.......
xyz..................peach.............yellow.....
```

I want to put this in a solr index so i can query-
1. itemcode:abc - it should list all documents with itemcode as abc
2. type:abc and color:red - it should list all documents with type abc and color as red.

I noticed this is relational data. Does solr support such data? What fields should i add in the schema?
 I thought of making 'type' and 'color' as multiValued, but then I would lose the relation type to color. Any ideas would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you are indexing your content you need to create 3 fields in SOLR as:

1) Itemcode

2) Type

3) Color

then using solr queries you wil be able to satisfy both of your queries

1. itemcode: abc - it should list all documents with itemcode as abc

Answer: itemcode:abc

1. type: abc and color:red - it should list all documents with type abc and color as red.

Answer: type:abc&color:red

Hope this Helps!!!

Comment: if your itemcode is uniquekey in your solr index then you wont be able to index the documents as you mentioned in your question.